# bundle ID issue - I can't get the Xcode bundle ID and the iTunes connect ID to reflect the same id

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have an iOS app I'm trying to submit and my app runs on my iPhone. I added the apple id account to Xcode and typed in my bundle id under the general section in Xcode then clicked "fix issue" which then resolved any code signing issues. That works.

Now on iTunes connect I tried to use the same bundle id i.e. com.blah.appName that was in Xcode and register it in iTunes connect. This wouldn't let me. On iTunes connect it said (for the bundle ID I was using to actually compile and run my app successfully on my iPhone in Xcode) "An App ID with Identifier 'com.blah.appName' is not available. Please enter a different string."

So I decided to register - in iTunes connect - a different bundle id. That registered successfully. So then in Xcode I tried to change the bundle ID in the general section in Xcode to the bundle ID I just registered in iTunes connect. I receive this error but in Xcode this time "An App ID with Identifier 'com.blahblah2.appName' is not available. Please enter a different string."

I'm not sure what to do here. It says that the bundle ids MUST be the same in Xcode and in iTunes connect when you submit your app and I'm having some issues with getting this resolved.

Please help, and thanks everyone.

Comment: Check that your `team` matches the developer account you're trying to submit with. Chances are you registered/used a bundle ID with your `personal`, local account that allows you to run apps on your phone which then becomes unavailable for use by any other `team`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you open up your "Build Setting" tab in Xcode and then scroll down to the section titled "Code signing". Within that section is a setting named "code signing identity" and underneath that pull down tab you will see "release". If release is set to "iOS Developer" you need to click it and change it to "iPhone Distribution: Team Name"  ...
These links helped me figure out apple's annoying processes...

http://www.raywenderlich.com/48750/testflight-sdk-tutorial
   &
http://www.raywenderlich.com/101790/ios-beta-testing-with-testflight-tutorial

Comment: For anyone else whos interested, I had to make sure the target and the project had the settings you mentioned. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I found the **bundle identifier** when first starting to make the project - you have an option to add your own identifier.

To find it you click the main project file in the top of the files on the left hand side labelled "project name" "M"

this will bring up the projects page with "**App Identity**" there you will find your chosen ***bundle identifier***, as well as other information such as Display name, Version and Build

I hope this helped!